# Writing rspec for controllers with params?

Tags: ruby, rspec, parameters, controllers

I have a controller which has the following method

```
class <controllername> < ApplicationController
 def method
  if params["c"]
   .....
  elsif params["e"]
   .....
  else
   .....
  end

 end

end
```

Now, I want to write rspec for the above code.

How can I write separate context for both the params and how will I mention them as a get method.

Comment: Could you add the code of your current attempts?

Comment: sry, I cant post the code here. Also, I thought it's of little importance here. I just need to know how to mention `if params["c"]` and `params["e"]` in rspec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try approach like this:

```
RSpec.describe <controllername>, :type => :controller do
  describe "GET my_method" do
    context "param 'c' is provided"
      get :my_method, { "c" => "sample value" }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    context "param 'e' is provided"
      get :my_method, { "e" => "sample value" }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it puts you in proper direction.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. This really sets me up in proper direction